# How do I cause distortion & bloating at a movable 3D coordinate

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to have mesh warp away from a movable point such as the center of this sphere or an empty, a pushing force from the center of the sphere outwards.

Are geometry nodes capable of accomplishing this effect?

How do I make this effect?

Example: Sphere in the middle warping the center of a rectangular box's mesh.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A million different ways.

For the exact picture you're demonstrating, I would probably combine vertex weight proximity with displacement:

[image]

That would probably end up looking the best for what you're after.  Assign all verts in the subdivided box to a group named "prox" then create modifiers as shown-- you're reweighting those verts based on how close they are to the surface of the sphere, and then moving them in the direction of their normals, a distance which is modulated by that group.

For what you're describing in words, a warp modifier is more exact:

[image]

Here, I've parented two empties to my sphere, and then use a warp modifier to transfer the difference in their transforms onto my box mesh.  "Empty" has no transform, but "Empty.001" has been scaled up, so nearby verts of the box will be scaled up around the sphere (not quite the same thing as moving in direction of normals above), and then the modifier defines a radius for the effect as well as a fall-off curve.

I said, "a million ways", and that's a bit of an exaggeration, but there are plenty more techniques to do this.  You could use a lattice.  Or a dynamic mesh deform.  Or an armature using bone envelopes.  Or geometry nodes.  Or data transferring weights from a moving target for a displace.  Or true displacement in your materials with driven values.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your 2 considerate answers. It's twice as much as I expected. I must try that double empty. It sound like a blast to experiment with.